# Proving a DTFT relation

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to prove that the inverse DTFT of: $$\frac{1}{1-ae^{-j\Omega }} $$where |a|<1 is:  $$a^{n}u[n]$$

The way to prove it is by the integral below but I'm not sure how to proceed:
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{-\pi }^{\pi } \frac{1}{1-ae^{-j\Omega }} e^{j\Omega n}d\Omega 
$$

Comment: Can you not go in the other direction, i.e., compute the forward transform of the presumed answer and verify that it matches the original? Anyhow, the integral should be easy to find using a complex contour integral. If you know about these …

Comment: I've done the other direction but I was curious about going back as it is a interesting integral. No, I don't know about complex contour integrals, I guess that's why I find it interesting. Are complex contour integrals are covered in a Complex Analysis or similar subject?

Comment: Indeed, that is where you learn about them. But you can do this integral without it. The fraction inside the integral is the sum of a geometric series. Substitute the series and integrate term by term, and you're done.

Comment: Ok so substituting the series gives $\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{-\pi }^{\pi }  [\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(ae^{-j\Omega})^n] e^{j\Omega n}d\Omega  $, the exponentials don't cancel do they as one is outside the series? The series does not include the second exponential.

Comment: You do need to multiply the second exponential into the sum. But first, pick a different summation index than $n$, or total confusion will ensue. Note that $\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{j\Omega}\,d\Omega=0$ if $\Omega$ is a non-zero integer! You also need to think about why you can move the integral inside the sum.

Comment: Using k as summation index: $\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{-\pi }^{\pi }  [\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }(ae^{-j\Omega})^k] e^{j\Omega n}d\Omega  $. Then you can move the integral inside the sum as it is equal to the sum of the integrals. Then becomes $\frac{1}{2\pi }\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }a^{k}\int_{-\pi }^{\pi } e^{j\Omega (n-k)}d\Omega = \frac{1}{2\pi }\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{a^{k}}{n-k}\left [ cos(\pi (n-k))-cos(\pi (n-k)) \right ]=0 $ as like you noted. Is that correct? If so it will always be zero as the all endpoints of integration with distance 2pi will result in zero. How does it become a^n?

Comment: Pretty much okay, but note that your little calculation is incorrect for one value of $k$, namely when $k=n$. That's where $a^n$ comes from.

Comment: Wow, I see that now! I appreciate your help Harald!